# How to use a set of characters in the javascript match method

Tags: javascript, regex, match

How can I use all the following characters as a regular expression in the javascript match method and escape the characters that need to be escaped?

~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|:;<>,./? and space

so that mysstring.match(REGEX) returns null only if mysstring does not contain any of the above set of characters

```
 "abc".match(REGEX) //should return null
 "abc@".match(REGEX) //should NOT return null (it has @)
 "ab c".match(REGEX) //should NOT return null (it has a space)
 "++abc".match(REGEX) //should NOT return null (it has +)
```

Comment: You should really just read the documentation on [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and the [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the characters in a set, so that the regular expression match a character in the string that is any of the characters in the set.

The `-` and `]` characters needs to be escaped when used in the set, and the `/` character needs to be escaped if you use a regular expression literal:

```
var REGEX = /[~!@#$%^&*()_\-+={}[\]|:;<>,.\/? ]/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want to match for a non-word character here. Just use `\W` for match:

```
var re = /[\W_]/;
"abc".match(re);
null
"abc@".match(re);
["@"]
"ab c".match(re);
[" "]
"++abc".match(re);
["+"]
```

Comment: That is easy to include by using `var re = /[\W_]/;`, see update.

Answer (score 0):

**Does this help?**

```
var REGEX = /[_\W0-9]/;
```

This expression checks for any special characters or spaces.
....and also only returned null for "abc".match(REGEX)